# Angular get request within rails app not working

Tags: ajax, http, angularjs, get, controller

I'm trying to make (my first) angular get request within a rails app to one of my routes.  I'm not sure why this is returning nothing, not even an error.

```
function accomplishmentController($scope, $http) { 

$scope.$apply(function() { 
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/users'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("hell0");
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("error");
  });
});
$scope.accomplishments = [];
$scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.accomplishments.unshift({ name: $scope.newAccomp, count: 0 });
  $scope.newAccomp = '';
}
$scope.addToCount = function() {
  var currentcount = this.accomp.count;
  this.accomp.count = currentcount + 1;
}
$scope.delete = function() {
  index = this.$index;
  $scope.accomplishments.splice(index, 1)
}
```

}

Comment: Check your consoles Network tab, what's the status of the request?

Comment: there was nothing in the network XHR

Comment: Request isn't being sent then. Any reason the request is inside a `$scope.apply`? The request will trigger a digest cycle so that isn't necessary

Comment: just experimenting with it and trying to learn what its about, but it doesn't work without that either.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `console.log` or `debugger` inside `accomplishmentController` to check your controller is actually used? Those `scope.$apply` calls should cause an error if the function is ever run in angular context (as it would if it's used as a controller)

Comment: i made a fiddle, you can see the code is working... im new to angular but doesnt that mean the controller is working? http://jsfiddle.net/natecraft/YPLEJ/